# Convert Float64Array to array

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Is there a built-in way to convert Javascript's [Float64Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Float64Array) to a normal array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
var normalArray = [].slice.call(floatArray);
```

Demo:

```
var floatArray = new Float64Array(4);
floatArray[3] = 3.0;
var normalArray = [].slice.call(floatArray);
console.log(normalArray);
//[0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Comment: It's nicer with a prototype... check my answer :D

Answer (score 7):

The original answer is quite old.
A more recent way to do it (ES6+) could be to use Array.from

```js
const floatArray = new Float64Array(4);
floatArray[3] = 3.0;
var normalArray = Array.from(floatArray);
console.log(normalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Float64Array.prototype.toArray = Array.prototype.slice;
const floatArray = new Float64Array(4);
floatArray[3] = 3.0125;
var normalArray = floatArray.toArray();
console.log(normalArray);
```