# How to correctly initialize vector of number in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types, typeerror

I'm having difficulties at initializing a variable with the value returned from a function.
The function is hosted [here](https://github.com/stdlib-js/array-linspace) and it should return an array of numbers.
So I try to define my variable as

```
import {default as linspace} from '@stdlib/array-linspace'

var xvalues:number[] = linspace(0,10, 10)
```

And the IDE gives me an error because `Type 'Float64Array' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': pop, push, concat, shift, and 5 more.ts(2740)`
So I checked what was actually being returned by the function with the following logs:

```
console.log(typeof linspace(0,10,10) )
console.log(typeof linspace(0,10,10)[0] )
```

And the types are in fact

```
Object
number
```

Then why defining my variable as `var xvalues:number[]` is not correct?

Comment: A `Float64Array` [is not a normal array](https://tsplay.dev/mbEg9N). You do not need to explicitly annotate `xvalues` either. TypeScript should infer it for you.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. I didn't know there was a difference. Post the answer so I can flag it solved. Also for anyone with a similar problem check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171818/convert-float64array-to-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you what type to use `Float64Array`:

```
let xvalues: Float64Array = linspace(0,10, 10)
```

*(`var` shouldn't be used in new code.)*

That said, there's no need for an explicit annotation, TypeScript will infer it for you:

```
let xvalues = linspace(0,10, 10)
```

> Then why defining my variable as var xvalues:number[] is not correct?

Because `number[]` and [`Float64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array) are different things. It's true that a `Float64Array` contains `number` values, but it's a *different* container than a standard array. It's also worth noting you'd have gotten the same result logging the type of an element value from a `Float32Array`, an `Int8Array`, or any other typed array other than `BigInt64Array` even though the contain different kinds of numbers, because when you access a value in a typed array, it's converted from its raw type (an 8-bit two's complement number, for instance, in the case of an `Int8Array`) to the plain `number` type.